# Eclipse CDT Luna - setting up custom gcc location

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-luna

In my setup we compile stuff from a custom gcc location, for example

> /customlocation/gcc/g++4.9

but whenever I try to create a new Eclipse project, it picks up the default compiler installed in the system, and I end up having header files that are not well managed.

At the moment I ended up manually disabling the CDT built in Compiler settings from

> Properties->C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths -> Providers

And I added manually all the include paths from

> /customlocation/gcc/g++4.9

However it is cumbersome to do it for every project.

Is there a way to tell Eclipse to use that custom location instead of the default system wide one?

Comment: I found it: in Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings - Tab Discovery. If I change the "Command to get compiler specs" to 

    /customlocation/gcc/g++4.9 it pulls in all the expected includes